# Get rid of the underline in Vim's fold name

Tags: vim

This is my setting for Vim's folding:

```
hi Folded term=bold ctermfg=White
```

How do I get rid of the underline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For attributes that you don't specify, the `:hi` command will keep the previous one. So if your colorscheme includes `cterm=underline`, you need to configure this:

```
hi Folded term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=White
```